# Sending Email Via CakePHP - Configuration email override the sender email

Tags: cakephp, gmail, cakephp-2.x, cakephp-2.7, cakeemail

I am having problem on sending email via cake php 2.7. Well, the email gets forwarded to the desired email address but there is problem in getting sender email address, as I am getting configuration email address in the place of sender email address. I have problem in getting how to fix this issue. It would be grateful if anybody could suggest anything regarding the issue.

Some parts of code are:

pages controller

```
public function sendEmail($data) {
    $email = new CakeEmail();
    $email->config('gmail');
    $email->emailFormat('html');
    $email->sender($data['User']['email_address'],$data['User']['name']);
    $email->from(array($data['User']['email_address'] => $data['User']['name']));   
    $email->to('configuration_email');
    $email->replyTo($data['User']['email_address']);
    $email->subject($data['User']['subject']);
    $message = 'Name: '.$data['User']['name'].'<br> How Did You Hear: '. $data['User']['how_did_you_hear'].
            '<br>Message: '.$data['User']['body'];

    if ($email->send($message))
    {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
  }
```

email.php

```
public $gmail = array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'configuration_email',
        'password' => 'password',       
        'transport' => 'Smtp'
        );
```

'From' field is using configuration email instead of using $data['User']['email'].

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gmail lets you send messages on behalf of an email address different from your Gmail address only if you already own that email account and it is properly registered in your Gmail account.

Instructions are described in [Gmail: Send mail from a different address or alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en):

**I'm a Gmail or Google Apps user sending from an external address.**

- Click the gear in the top right .
- Select **Settings**.

  1. Click the Accounts and Import tab.
  2. Under Send mail as, click **Add another email address**.
  3. In the 'Email address' field, enter your name and alternate email address you own.
  4. Enter the SMTP server (e.g. smtp.domain.com), your username on that domain, and your password for that account. You may also need to adjust your port setting or SSL setting (talk to your other ISP if you need this information).
  5. Click **Add account >>**
  6. Open your other account and either click the link in the message Gmail sent or enter the confirmation code in the Accounts and Import section of your Gmail settings.

     - If Gmail sent a verification email and you didn’t receive it, try checking your Spam or Bulk Mail folders for a message from account-verification-noreply@google.com to see if the email ended up in there.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The thing is, in my program anyone can create an account and could send the queries via contact page to the configuration email. In this case, is it possible to send email from his/her email address?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible. You could set a local SMTP server and allow it to relay email for any domain, but the deliverability would be really low, as most SMTP servers check the SPF records as a means to fight spam. It would also be abused by spammers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is appreciable. (y)